# What would the opposite if this office 365 powershell command?

Tags: powershell, office365

I gave a mailbox full access to all mailboxes and now i need to revert this process back.

I don't want to remove folder permission or anything, just the full access or the opposite of this command.

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Add-MailboxPermission -User "myemail@domain.com" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType all
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `Remove-MailboxPermission`

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited | Remove-MailboxPermission -User "myemail@domain.com" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType all
```

For more Information see the [Remove-MailboxPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/remove-mailboxpermission?view=exchange-ps) Documentation

**Side note:** You can use the `-WhatIf` Parameter for most of the cmdlets that make changes to an object, this way you can first check if the change is right before actually run it...